# How do I check if a line or a linear object 3d is perfectly straight along the X axis for example?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, axis

Being a not too complicated question I have found a myriad of similar questions about it but it seems to me that they do not fully answer what I am looking for, which is actually much simpler than it seems. If there is already any question that can answer this please link it to me.

In my walls the different sections are clearly crooked, so when I go to join them, a small crack remains. I tried to fix everything manually but sooner or later something gets distorted somewhere else. My question is this:

1). Is there a tool similar to the '' leveler '' that can tell me if the object or the selection line is perfectly straight along its axis?

2). Alternatively, is there a way to straighten everything, in this case along the x axis, horizontally?

I have already tried different methods, I always use shortcuts to make sure I always move straight along the axes, but now I don't know what is straight and what is not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to make sure a line of edges is straight along an axis, you can select them all and scale them along an orthogonal axis by 0. Be careful though about the origin point of the transformation, by default it will be the median of the geometry, but you can force it to be the 3D cursor or the currently selected vertex for instance

Comment: Could you show me an example? in my case I have several strips of tiles created on a plane that I have to stack one on top of the other, to form a large wall. but they seem not to be perfectly straight along the x axis. @Gorgious

Comment: Select your vertices in edit mode, press S, Z , 0 then S, Y, 0 and they  should be aligned along X axis

Comment: no in doing so, everything and all the vertices are aligned in a precise point, altering the shape of the object. @Gorgious

Comment: Makes everything flat.

Comment: Maybe I should have done this before but by now I have built 3D shapes, and even working in object mode it flattens everything.

Comment: Oh, right, if the object is 3D this will make everything flat. You could use a combination of vertex groups + shrinkwrap modifier or lattice modifier... Are you able to share one of these tiles so I can see if this would work out ? You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yes, I had to express immediately that they were 3D objects.
It is actually a much bigger project than a tile. it's a building.
the movements are millimetric obviously not perceived, but the difference in height can be noticed from very close.
I'm uploading the file to g-drive because it weighs too much, soon I'll upload it.

Comment: I'll take a look but unfortunately I can sense this will be very time consuming if your project is almost-done already...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116563/discussion-between-albizz-and-gorgious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Here's a video- This could be a way for you to do this.
   [Video: Blender: How to Align Vertices, Edges or Faces - Revised](https://youtu.be/1c-imsuEVYE)
2. Also the align tools options. [Video: Align tools](https://youtu.be/USFD5Yuqm94)

[image: Align tools]

3. For more exact dimensions there's a good tutorial that has helped me.  I do a lot of 3D printing and I use Blender as my CAD modeller along with the Cad Transform plug-in.
   [Video: Cad Transform plug-in](https://youtu.be/TWEoZghkalc)

Comment: So, thank you for replying. the first point does not help me as it concerns the 2d. the second point, I can't understand how this align tool works, I click on the coordinates but absolutely nothing changes. while the third point, it looks like a really great add-on, I downloaded it right away and I'll take a look at the video you shared. It should help me a lot.

Comment: @Albizz  Here's a video that goes into the align tool https://youtu.be/USFD5Yuqm94